# Frame Tool vs Smart Object Layer for mockups in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I'm wondering why majority of the mockups available online utilize Smart Object layer for containing a placeholder image rather than a Frame?

It just feels like frames are easier to work with, am I missing something?

Comment: I have very little experience using frames... Can they be distorted/warped? Because aside from the relatively easy swapping of images, that's the other major reason why mockups use SO's and not like raster layers.

Answer (score 2):

Frames are a **new feature** and weren't available for many years before. `:)` This is why you also will find older tutorials relying on stroking paths with a brush, rather than using the stroke options for vector paths, or clone stamping rather than using the content aware tools.

In addition, what *you* find easier for *your workflow* may not fit for the workflow others use. Just use what works for you. That's all tutorials essentially do - explain what works for *that* author.

I would also point out that there is **very** different functionality between frames and smart objects. Frames essentially create a layer mask easily. That's all. Frames *don't* care what the layer contains. Smart Objects reference/retain the *original resolution* of a placed image or group of layers. You *can* have a Frame applied to a Smart Object Layer. It's *not* "one or the other" so to speak. Frames are more a substitute for *Layer Masks*, not Smart Objects.

It's kind of like watching a film set in the 1800s and asking why everyone is using horses when cars are so much better. Horses are still used today because they *are* still better for some tasks.

Comment: Thanks! Loved the horse vs cars comparison :)

Comment: @genesst Also frames can't have Smart Filters, which some mockups may rely on.